# databricks notebook widgets recreate uses cached value issue

Tags: databricks

removing and recreating databricks notebook widgets does not work. this mechanism was being btq-sort eval notebook

```
dbutils.widgets.text("widget_param", 'temp')

widget_param = dbutils.widgets.get("widget_param")
print(f'initial widget_param: {widget_param}')
# initial widget_param: temp

print('removing widget'
dbutils.widgets.remove("widget_param")

new_widget_value = 'temp2'
try:
    print('verifying widget removed')
    print(f'mlflow_run_id in widget: {dbutils.widgets.get("widget_param")}')
except Exception as e:
    print('Widget not set!')

# verifying widget removed
# Widget not set!

print(f'recreate widget with new default value: {new_widget_value}')
# recreate widget with new default value: temp2

dbutils.widgets.text("widget_param", defaultValue=new_widget_value)
print(f'New widget_param in widget: {dbutils.widgets.get("widget_param")}')
# New widget_param in widget: temp
```

why is it not setting new value? is there a way to clear dbutils cache ? any workaround?
I need it to be able to share params across %scala and %python  envs